# In C++03, how to conditionally declare a static data member of a template class, based on type traits

Tags: c++, sfinae, template-specialization, type-traits, c++03

**Background**

Consider that I would like to, **in C++03**, implement the following contrived construct:

> **(+)**
>
> ```
> template< typename T >  // parameter list must contain T but may otherwise modified
> struct foo;
> ```
>
> If the type trait `dummy_trait<T>::value` over the template parameter
>   `T` of `foo` is `true`, then `foo` should contain a static data member
>   named `value`, of type `T`, initialized with the integer literal expression `42`; otherwise there should be no static data
>   member named `value`.

with e.g. the following `dummy_trait` (actual dummy trait may differ):

> ```
> template< typename T >
> struct dummy_trait { static const bool value = false; };
>
> template<>
> struct dummy_trait<int> { static const bool value = true; };
> ```

**Question(s)**

- Are there any other (possibly more appropriate) alternatives to implement **(+)**, in addition to the two approaches below?
- Are there any pitfalls or aspects to carefully bear in mind using any of the two approaches below?

---

**Approaches of my own**

Using the helper

```
template< bool B, typename T = void >
struct enable_if {};

template< typename T >
struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };
```

Either e.g. using partial class template specialization:

```
// (A)
template< typename T, typename Enable = void >
struct foo {};

template< typename T >
struct foo<T, typename enable_if<dummy_trait<T>::value>::type > { 
    static const T value = 42; 
};
```

Or e.g. <strike>leveraging SFINAE</strike> introducing a conditional (on the trait) error on the declaration of the static data member:

```
// (B)
template< typename T >
struct foo {
    static const typename enable_if<
        dummy_trait<T>::value, T >::type value = 42;
};
```

If I'm not mistaken, `(A)` above would allow using `foo` also for instantiations with types `T` where `dummy_trait<T>::value` is `false` (although there would be no `value` member of `foo`), whereas such instantiations would not be possible at all if using `(B)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there any other (possibly more appropriate) alternatives to implement (+), in addition to the two approaches below (leveraging SFINAE)?

Not a great difference from your solution (A) but... you can obtain the result through inheritance

```
template <typename T>
struct foo : public bar<T>
 { };
```

Where `bar` is as follows.

```
template <typename T, bool = dummy_trait<T>::value>
struct bar { };

template <typename T>
struct bar<T, true> { static const T value = 42; };
```

You can also see `bar` as simpler way (no `enable_if`) to obtain `foo`.

> Are there any pitfalls or aspects to carefully bear in mind using any of the two approaches below?

The only pitfall I see is the one you have just seen: the (B) method doesn't works because you cant define `foo` when `dummy_trait<T>::value` is `false`.

I mean... (B) isn't SFINAE because substitution failure, in this case, **is** an error.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice alternative, and it may go better with a linter I'm currently stuck with, one that tends to derail even from the most simple template meta-programming constructs. Good point regarding (B), thanks.